# How Do I Use A Caching Proxy WIth debootstrap?

Tags: proxy, debootstrap

I want to run `debootstrap` and create a distro multiple times without constantly downloading packages.

Using `apt-cacher-ng` or the `--foreign` option in debootstrap doesn't work completely offline (e.g. if I am doing this on the train) because debootstrap will still try to connect to the internet to get the InRelease file from the remote repo.

It seems like squid (or some other caching proxy) should be able to be configured to cache certain urls so that when I am offline I can still run the process.

What should I install and how should I configure it to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you `apt install squid-deb-proxy` you can run debootstrap offline (even the `InRelease` files).

However, if you want to save bandwidth and continue to use the offline file once you are are online again you need to modify it slightly.

There are absolute paths in the `squid-deb-proxy.conf` file so you need to make a copy of it in your project and modify it.

Find the references to `/etc` and `/var` and modify them to be relative to separate it from the system files.

In order to still use the proxy when you are online you need to add this to the conf file.

```
#Use cached values when offline
offline_mode on
```

You can then start it like this:

```
mkdir -p squid/var/log/squid-deb-proxy
mkdir -p squid/var/run/

echo "Starting an instance of squid using the working dir for caches and logs instead of the system dirs"
squid -Nf squid/squid-deb-proxy.conf
```

Then before you start `debootstrap`

```
#Use a caching proxy to save bandwidth
export http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:8000
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a proxy to solve this. `debootstrap` has a command line flag `--cache-dir` which provides the same functionality. Not sure if this was available at the time of this question.

```
debootstrap --help
Usage: debootstrap [OPTION]... <suite> <target> [<mirror> [<script>]]
Bootstrap a Debian base system into a target directory.
    ...
    --cache-dir=DIR        Use specified directory as package cache directory
    ...
```